# Unable to view embedded images in HTMLBody on WebView2

Tags: html, vb.net, forms, webview2

I am trying to read emails from Microsoft Outlook into a WinForms(VB.NET) app. I can load emails from Outlook and then display the HTMLBody into Webview2 but the images show a broken icon. The images in the HTMLBody appear to be embedded and are of this format:

```html
<img border=0 width=89 height=49 style='width:.9236in;height:.5069in' id="Picture_x0020_3" src=cid:image002.png@01XXXXXX.6144X4XX>
```

I have used many workarounds shown already which is using `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping`. My code looks like this:

```vb
' Get the email body as HTML content
Dim htmlBody As String = selectedMailItem.HTMLBody 

' Create a new local folder to store the HTML content
Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Temp\"

Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath) 

' Create a unique file name for the HTML content
Dim fileName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5) + ".html"
Dim filePath As String = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName) 

' Save the HTML content to the local file
File.WriteAllText(filePath, htmlBody) 

' Map the virtual host name to the local folder
Await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)

' MsgBox(folderPath)

webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping("localhost", folderPath, CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors)

' Load the HTML content into the WebView control
Dim c_nav As String = (http://localhost/ + fileName) 

'webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(c_nav)

webView.Source = New Uri(c_nav)
```

I settled with saving it in a temporary file which I plan to implement a method of deleting immediately after. I tried to read it normally from HTMLBody using .NavigateToString and it obviously didn't work since it does not support additional web resources. For CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors, I tried it with .Allow and .Deny and I still got the broken image icon. Is there any other workaround I can try or am I doing it wrong?

I was expecting the images to load properly

Comment: Check c_nav your code doesn'tlook like it produces the correct string

Comment: Everything reads correctly except the images not loading properly

Comment: Don't use `localhost` as your SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping hostname. I'm not sure if that's what is causing your images to not load, but either way you shouldn't replace the meaning of localhost. You should use a hostname like `app.example`. Ending with `.example` avoids a potential perf issue as well.

Comment: Okay  thanks, didn't make any difference though